# How to pin Azure Application Insights Analytics query to dashboard when "NO RESULTS FOUND"

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-application-insights, azureportal

Within the Azure portal -> Application Insights -> Analytics I have written a query (that is valid) but currently returns no results.  I want to pin the query to a dashboard but this does not appear to be possible because the pin icon does not appear unless results are returned.

Why is this and is there anyway to get around this?  I want the query (graph) setup on dashboard now so when data starts appearing it will start showing something meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

You can pin a mock query, e.g:

```
print 5
```

and then edit it on the dashboard:

[Editing a query on the dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcx5h.png)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way how to do it directly from a portal.

You can do it with resources.azure.com. Simply pin some working query and than update this query in resources.azure.com.